# CSS properties which can have colors as value

Tags: css

I'm creating a small utility to manipulate colors in javascript, and I wish to change colors on a webpage on the fly. There seem to be many CSS declarations which expect/support a color as the value, e.g:

```
color: red;
background[-color]: green;
border-color: red;
box-shadow: 0 0 4px blue;
fill: blue;
outline-color: green;
```

I've tried googling what declarations are of this kind, but I'm coming back empty handed. Is there any canonical list out there?

Comment: https://cssvalues.com/ can help a little bit maybe.

Comment: But what about complex coloring like gradient ?

Comment: Parsing CSS using javascript will be a bit tedious. It's easy to manipulate colors when you use CSS variables, https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp Just define variables for each color and then change the variable value in javascript.